# m2m returns None

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

When a user changes the URL of an object, the object should be removed and a new object should be created:

```
    ### other fields here ###

    issue = models.ManyToManyField(Issue, null=False, blank=False,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_url = self.url

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.url != self.__original_url:
            my_new_object = MyModel.objects.create(####)
            my_new_object.save()
            my_new_object.issue.add(self.issue)
```

The problem is that self.issue is retuning None.
I also tried

```
my_new_object.issue.add(MyModel.objects.get(pk = self.id).issue)
```

Same thing. 
What's wrong with this ?

Comment: Are you sure that `self.issue` is populated at the time of adding it to the new `my_new_object` instance? Also are you sure that your code gets executed, as in, does it pass `if self.url != self.__original_url` check?

Comment: The if passes the test, so the code is executed, the m2m issue is populated but it returns None. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following one:

```
obj = my_new_object.save(commit=False)
obj.issue.add(self.issue) 
obj.save()
```

Comment: Isn't commit only used with ModelForm ? This is not my case, I am working inside the model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`my_new_object.issue.add(self.issue)`

where you basically try to add a QuerySet instead of an instance.

Try with:

```
issues = self.issue.all()
for issue in issues:
    self.issue.add(issue)
```

or more concise:

```
my_new_object.issue.add(*self.issue.all())
```